# Use of unowned inside the closure of the closure for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I have a closure inside a closure, and the second closure use self, so both should have unowned self or just the second closure should have it?

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) { [unowned self] () -> Void in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [unowned self] () -> Void in
        self.doSomething()
    })
}
```

Comment: try draw retain graph on paper, can you find a cycle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the retain graph *without* `unowned`, it doesn't have any cycles so you don't need `unowned` to break anything.

`a -> b` means a retain b

```
backgroundQueue -> outerBlock -> self
                       |          ^
                       V          |
      mainQueue -> innerBlock -----
```

A cycle is formed only when `self` retain any of the blocks.

Also note even `backgroundQueue` does retain `outerBlock`, the block will be released after executed, so in case self retain `backgroundQueue`, the retain cycle will not hold on.

---

This is the retain graph *with* `unowned` (your code)

`a -x- b` means a use b without retain it (unowned)

```
  backgroundQueue -> outerBlock -x- self
                           |          |
                           V          x
          mainQueue -> innerBlock -----
```

you can see `self` is *not* retained by anything, which means when innerBlock is executed, self may be deallocated and cause your app crash.

Comment: @DanielG.R. draw it yourself? it isn't hard. or you can use instruments to check leaks in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> both should have unowned self or just the second closure should have it?

None of the above. If you are just doing `dispatch_async`, the `[unowned self]` is a mistake. Delete it in both places. *Neither* needs it.